# Traverse simplexml_load_file object recieved from Google Maps REST API with non-unique element names

Tags: php, xml, google-maps, simplexml

I am trying to get the value inside the `<address_component>` element that corresponds to `<type>postal_code</type>` from the XML returned by the Google maps REST API.

For example, in the below:

```
    ...

  <result>    
    <type>
      route
    </type>    
    <formatted_address>
      Rose Ln, Liverpool, Merseyside L18 5ED, UK
    </formatted_address>    
    <address_component>      
      <long_name>
        Rose Ln
      </long_name>      
      <short_name>
        Rose Ln
      </short_name>      
      <type>
        route
      </type>      
    </address_component>    
    <address_component>      
      <long_name>
        Liverpool
      </long_name>      
      <short_name>
        Liverpool
      </short_name>      
      <type>
        locality
      </type>      
      <type>
        political
      </type>      
    </address_component>    
    <address_component>      
     ...      
    </address_component>    
    <address_component>      
    ...
    </address_component>    
    <address_component>      
      <long_name>
        L18 5ED
      </long_name>      
      <short_name>
        L18 5ED
      </short_name>      
      <type>
        postal_code
      </type>      
    </address_component>    
    <address_component>      
    ...      
    </address_component>    
   ...    
  </result>

  ... more result elements
```

We see one of the `<result>` elements. Nested inside are multiple `<address_component>` elements. Inside one of those is `<type>postal_code</type>`.

My question is how would I distinguish between these same named elements and choose only the `<address_component>` with `<type>postal_code</type>` attributed to it?

If they were uniquely named it would be a simple case of:

```
foreach ($address_rsponse->result as $address_option) {
    $val = $address_option->some_unique_name;      
}
```

However when named the same I am stumped as to a method to pick out an element by it's child-element.

Could anyone shed any light on the correct approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) with SimpleXML ([docs](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.xpath)).

The following will give you an array containing the `<address_component>` element(s) that you're looking for.

```
$address_rsponse->result->xpath(
    'address_component[normalize-space(type)="postal_code"]')
```

If you want to loop over the `<result>` elements, the following will give you an array containing the `<address_component>` element(s) that you're looking for and output the first for each `<result>`.

```
foreach ($address_rsponse->result as $result) {
    $postal_codes = $result->xpath('address_component[normalize-space(type)="postal_code"]');
    // Do whatever with the postal code(s)
    echo trim($postal_codes[0]->long_name);
}
```

Comment: Great stuff! I used it in the context of a single ->result element and it work excellently there too. Thanks